# Unable to loop through collection - backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Below is my json structure and after collection fetch i'm unable to loop through it.

JSON :

```
{ "science":[{},{},{},...{}], "maths":[{},{},{},...{}], "english":[{},{},{},...{}], }

this.collection.each(function(m) {
    //returns me only only single child object named "r"
    //screenshot attached below
});
```

How can i loop 3 times i.e for 3 diff array objects ?

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about the structure of your data? Or do you just want to loop through the 3 array attributes of this particular model?

Comment: I want to loop through such that i get the 3 attributes..science,mathematics and aviation. As of now it just iterates once and shows a single object named "r"

Comment: The 3 attributes you're talking about are Model's attributes. You're trying to loop through your collection, therefore you get a model (that object "r" is a model, for more explanation about why this name I could give you a link but that's not the point). What structure do you expect (obviously not this one)?

Comment: I've created a jsbin - http://jsbin.com/ataher/1/ . console.log(model) shows single model instead i want 3 models..

Comment: I still don't really know what you want. Do you want 3 models (one for science, one for maths and one for aviation) which have like a "data" attribute that would be an array containing your objects?

Comment: yes correct 3 models..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change the JSON that contains your data. A collection will parse the JSON you give it:

```
[{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

Here we have an array with 3 objects. That will be parsed to 3 models. So you want something like that:

```
[
  {course: 'science', data: [...]},
  {course: 'maths', data: [...]},
  {course: 'aviation', data: [...]}
]
```

This will give you a collection with 3 models, and each of those models will have 2 attributes: one attribute `course` and one `data`. Now, to loop through them:

```
this.collection.each(function(m) {
  console.log(m.get('course')); // will be science, maths or aviation
  console.log(m.get('data')); // will be the corresponding array
});
```